# Is there a way to use an array of objects to populate choices in inquirer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirer

How do I get the choices to be just a specific value from all objects in the array?

Here's an example array:

```
var array = 
[{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
},
{
 a: 3,
 b: 4,
},
{
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
}]
```

And then later the inquirer is something like:

```
inquirer
.prompt({
  name: "test",
  type: "list",
  message: "Example Question",
  choices: [{array.b}]
})
```

My desired result would be the following as inquirer options for the list question:

```
[2,4,6]
```

Comment: `array.map(it => it.b)`

Comment: Or, more generally, `const choose = (name, array) => array .map(x => x[name])` called as `choose('b', array) //=> [2, 4, 6]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the b values only you can use lodash map and iterator methods to achieve that.
Ex:

`_.map(array, _.iteratee('b'); // [2,4,6]`